# How can I set code::blocks to link the project linker options before the target linker options?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, codeblocks

I need to link a library which has dependencies on a few other libraries. A different version of the library is required for each target (such as "debug" and "release"). This is not the case for the dependencies, and so I simply tried to put them in the project's linker options (in opposed to copying and pasting the entire list of linker options for each target). However, code::blocks links the target-specific linker options before the project linker options so it gets linked in the wrong order. Is there any way I can change the order of which they're linked?

Answer (score 0):

For each target in your project, C::B allows you to select one of four policies
for sequencing target options and project options when invoking build tools. In your
project:-

- Navigate **Build options** -> *Target* (e.g. `Debug`, `Release`)
- On the right in the **Project build options** panel, click to open the
  dropdown menu labelled **Policy**
- Choose one of:

  - **Use project options only**
  - **Use target options only**
  - **Prepend target options to project options**
  - **Append target options to project options**
- OK out.

It appears that you have **Prepend** configured at present and and want to configure
**Append**.